# What's the proper way to get nginx to translate ~user/* locations to ~user/public_html in the user's home directory?

Tags: nginx

What's the proper way to get nginx to translate `~user/*` locations to `~user/public_html` in the user's home directory, like Apache can do?  Seems like this should work, but it doesn't:

```
   location ~ ^/~([^\/]+)(.*)$ {
            alias /home/$1/public_html$2;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;
            autoindex on;
            try_files $uri =404; # Prevents exploit
    }
```

Comment: It should work for static files. I guess, it doesn't work for PHP files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nginx, php-fpm and tilde user directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20918988/nginx-php-fpm-and-tilde-user-directories)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you MSW.  The correct snippet I was looking for was

> location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*)?$ {
>          alias /home/$1/public_html$2;
>          autoindex on;
>   }